# SQL query in the correct order

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need to query data from the emp table to get the following result:

```
Dept No       Emp no      Emp Name        Mgr Name
---------------------------------------------------
10              7782      CLARK           KING
10              7934      MILLER          CLARK
20              7902      FORD            JONES
20              7369      SMITH           FORD
20              7876      ADAMS           SCOTT
20              7566      JONES           KING
20              7788      SCOTT           JONES
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.deptno AS "Dept No", e.empno AS "Emp No", e.ename AS "Emp Name", m.ename AS "Mgr Name"
FROM emp e, emp m
WHERE e.deptno IN (10,20) AND e.mgr = m.empno
ORDER BY "Dept No";
```

Unfortunately my Emp Name and Mgr Name columns are not being displayed in an order that matches the example:

```
Dept No       Emp No      Emp Name        Mgr Name
---------------------------------------------------
10              7782      CLARK           KING
10              7934      MILLER          CLARK
20              7369      SMITH           FORD
20              7566      JONES           KING
20              7788      SCOTT           JONES
20              7876      ADAMS           SCOTT
20              7902      FORD            JONES
```

How do I order the last two columns so that they display in the order that I need them to?

Comment: How is the order determined?

Comment: You need to specify the order in the query that you want. The default order obtained by `SELECT` isn't guaranteed to be a particular desired order. It's not clear from your example what determines the order you want. After ordering by dept no, it does not appear to be ordered by any of the other attributes.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Emp name and Mgr name are both unordered in your expected result, so just don't bother to order them.

Comment: You need to go back to whoever set your assignment and ask them to define the rules which govern the sort order. Because your posted result set seems to be ordered randomly with `deptno` so there's no way we can provide a better solution than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

To order by multiple columns you can just add a comma and the name of the next field you want to sort by, in order of importance.

Ex:

```
ORDER BY "Dept No", "Emp Name", "Mgr Name"
```

I'm not sure what your desired order is for the columns, but that's the generalized answer.